# div with triangular arrow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I am using bootstrap and wish to give triangular pointer to div just like below

[image]

I have tried some code see below

```
<div>This is just test</div>
<div class="tip">Testing div 12455555553ssssssssaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

But arrow is going somewhere else.

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/58/)

Also is it possible to increase width of div when i hover over the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.tip:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    top: -7px;
    content: '';
}

.tip:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #eee;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 2;
    top: -6px;
    content: '';
}
```

or if you want more browser support instead of `transform:translateX(-50%)` you can use a negative `margin-left`

Comment: Is it possible to move arrow to left. Right now its on right. Where is setting to move the arrow? Also any idea how to increase width of div when i hover over it?

Comment: just change value of left to something you want ex:10px and remove transform, to increase width you coul use div:hover{width:250px}, will increase width with 50px

Comment: Where exactly? I tried in .tip before but not working? Also do tell me how to increase width of triangle?

Comment: Wow. Just few questions. What did you did to move to left and how to increase width of triangle? Also why text is moving out of div?

Comment: look at the code, for moving to left i changed value of left for both, :before and :after pseudo elements, i changed the width with ..tip:hover, which is at bottom of css, i added also a transition to make element scale smoother . text is going outside of div because the word is too long, you can change that with overflow-wrap. hope it helps

Comment: In .tip.hover you just have this transform:scale(1.1); I want to increase width of that triangle

Comment: Also it doesnt work in IE. I checked that when you hover then it doesnt increases width of div in IE

Comment: By the way i am using IE 9

Comment: try using chrome or firefox , for ie9 you need to use vendor prefix for transforms, i omitted them, anyway if you have more questions move this discution in chat

Comment: I am still not getting option to move discussion in chat. can you invite me?

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to do that

Comment: I will accept your answer and then you might get option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73569/discussion-between-happy-and-alin-mercasi).

Comment: I have asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210414/not-able-to-arrange-in-rows-and-columns