# not able to arrange in rows and columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to arrange in rows and columns. So using bootstrap's row class but not able to arrange in columns and rows. here is my code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="float:left;padding-left:0;padding-right:0">
      <div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tip">
        <h3><a href="#"  title="Elgen i baksetet">Test block1</a></h3>
        <em><a href="#">AAAA</a></em> 
        <p>Test paragraph 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="float:left;padding-left:0;padding-right:0">
      <div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tip">
        <h3><a href="#>Test block 2</a></h3>
        <em><a href="#">BBBB</a></em> 
        <p>New paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="  col-md-4 " style="float:left;padding-left:0;padding-right:0">
      <div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tip">
        <h3><a href="#">New title</a></h3>
        <em><a href="#">Title block 3</a></em> 
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="float:left;padding-left:0;padding-right:0">
      <div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tip">
        <h3><a href="#">Title3</a></h3>
        <em><a href="#">Title block 4</a></em>

        <p>Paragrpah start</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="float:left;padding-left:0;padding-right:0">
      <div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tip">
        <h3><a href="#">FFFFFFFFFFF</a></h3>
        <em><a href="#">GGGGGGGGG</a></em>

        <p>GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="  col-md-4 " style="float:left;padding-left:0;padding-right:0">
      <div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="tip">
        <h3><a href="#" title="Leasingforløpet">Gdddfdf</a></h3>
        <em><a href="#">aaagr</a></em>

        <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/97/)

Rows amd columns are getting mixed. Can someone tell me how can i fix it

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? because your bootstrap grid is generally fine. Only those tooltips look bad, maybe use bootstrap popover instead? Also avoid using inline styling like (`style="float:left;padding-left:0;padding-right:0”`) and use stylesheet instead.

Comment: @Dmonix you can see that my rows and columns are messed up. I have image and text below it. When i hover over text then my div increases its height. Hence i used tip. How to acheive it using popover? I wan to align my rows and column like this http://wet-boew.github.io/wet-boew-styleguide/v4/design/grids-en.html#example-fluid   Refer mobile and desktop section in that link

Comment: @Dmonix Also i cannot use popovers as those are displayed when something is clicked. In my case my text will always be there in div below images and when i hover over text then that div increases its height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your HTML and CSS a bit (see HTML in Fiddle)

```
.tip {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tip:hover {
  height:100%;
  transition:all .5s;
}

.tip .text {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tip:hover .text {
  height: 100%;
}

.img-responsive {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.relative {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Is this is what you want: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/108/)?

Comment: I wanted 3*3 display. Mean 3 rows and 3 columns

Comment: Also when you hover over text the text should overlap somepart of image. At the moment when i hover over its height increases but it doesnt overlap some part of image

Comment: Please help me. Now i can get 3*3 display but when i hover over text then its not overlapping image.

Comment: For more example please refer this website http://minleasing.no/
Thats exactly i want to achieve

Comment: Example page was very helpful, I’ve updated my Fiddle.

Comment: The height of div is not increasing but it is just overlapping image. In example website you can see that when you hover then it increases its height

Comment: I fixed the height issue but there is gap between images.

Comment: can i ask small question? I need one more div by side as you had seen in example website. The div which had Facebook. How to arrange that div by side.

Comment: To add extra column for Facebook stuff you need to change your grid. Wrap your current image rows into `.col-md-9` div and add `.col-md-3` div for Facebook. I’ve updated Fiddle.